# HTML input type radio value doesn't return correct val().length

Tags: jquery, html

The following is a part of a form where the user should fill in some data and choose some radio options.

```
<span>Phone</span>
<input type="radio" value="Phone" id="PreferableContactMethod" name="PreferableContactMethod" required>

<span>Email</span>
<input type="radio" value="Email" id="PreferableContactMethod" name="PreferableContactMethod" required>
```

To Validate my form I am using the below JQuery function

```
function validate(){
if (
    $('#FirstName').val().length   >   0   &&
    $('#LastName').val().length  >   0   &&
    $('#PreferableContactMethod').val().length    >   0
    )

{
    $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    $('input[type=submit]').val('Submit Form');

}else {
    $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    $('input[type=submit]').val('Fill in all required fields to Submit Form');
}
```

**This function works fine with all my input fields, however it doesn't work with  input type radio**

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Works perfectly here: http://jsfiddle.net/q9sjxjrn/ anything else going on you haven't included?

Comment: FYI IDs must be unique!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with it to get the value of the selected checkbox:

```
$("input[name='PreferableContactMethod']:checked").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't have same `id` on more than one element. You should use `$("input[name=PreferableContactMethod]")` to select your radio buttons. And to check if one of them is selected, use `$("input[name=PreferableContactMethod]:checked").length`.